# Codeigniter REST server API_key vs Token confused

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, rest, codeigniter-2

I am currently facing a dilemma, in this case the default value of the API-Key is X-API-KEY .

Currently i am using PHIL STURGEON rest server for codeigniter.

What i want to find out is the API-Key field, is it suppose to be for use to be like a secret key to authenticate the application using the api. And when we want to find out the current logged in user, we must make our own class and set another token key.

This would be like a two layer security where every request must have a api key to allow the client is use then api but also have a special token key to act like a session to find out the  current user who is logged in.

Or is the api-key suppose to be use to validated the current logged in user which acts as a session, but not to be used as a security against people from calling your api.

So in summary is the API-Key used to authenticate the application or is it used to authenticate the user?

Answer (score 0):

An API-Key is used to  authenticate the user. 
In theory you must not save state ( ex: current_user) in a REST Api. Each call must be standalone.

Comment: I think you mean authenticate the person or app using your api but the current user